# I want to show google custom search results in another page and under a different div

Tags: javascript, html, search

I want to integrate google's custom search engine into my website. I put the search box to navbar in my `index.html` page so GCSE shows results in the `navbar` section unpleasantly but I want to show search results in `search-page.html` and under `arkaplan` div. How can I do this? Is there any javascript code for this situation? Also, I used the form get method and I couldn't take any results.

My `index.html` is like this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
        integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Dancing+Script:wght@700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Open+Sans&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="img/favicon.png" />
    <title>Example Page</title>

</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="ct-content">
            <div class="header-img">
                <img src="img/header-cloud.jpg" alt="header">
                <h1 class="header-yazi">Example Page</h1>
            </div>
            <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-primary">
                <div class="container-fluid">
                    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">examplepage.com</a>
                    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse"
                        data-bs-target="#navbarNavDropdown" aria-controls="navbarNavDropdown" aria-expanded="false"
                        aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                    </button>
                    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse justify-content-center" id="navbarNavDropdown">
                        <ul class="navbar-nav text-center ">
                            <li class="nav-item ">
                                <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Ana Sayfa</a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                                <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" role="button"
                                    data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                                    Rüyalar
                                </a>
                                <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
                                    <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Home Page</a></li>
                                    <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Google</a></li>
                                    <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Custom</a></li>
                                    <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Search</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>

                            <li class="nav-item">
                                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Example 1</a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="nav-item">
                                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Example 2</a>
                            </li>

                            <li class="nav-item">
                                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Example 3</a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="nav-item">
                                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Example 4</a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="nav-item">
                                <a class="nav-link yesil" href="/search-page.html">Search Page</a>
                            </li>

                        </ul>
                        <form>
                            <script async src="https://cse.google.com/cse.js?cx=1234567890"></script>
                            <div class="gcse-search"></div>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
        </div>
        </nav>
```

My `search-page.html` is like this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
        integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/149bed2a73.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Dancing+Script:wght@700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Open+Sans&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="img/favicon.png" />
    <title>Example Page</title>

</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="header-img">
            <img src="img/header-cloud.jpg" alt="header">
            <h1 class="header-yazi">Example Page</h1>
        </div>
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-primary">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">examplepage.com</a>
                <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse"
                    data-bs-target="#navbarNavDropdown" aria-controls="navbarNavDropdown" aria-expanded="false"
                    aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                </button>
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse justify-content-center" id="navbarNavDropdown">
                    <ul class="navbar-nav text-center ">
                        <li class="nav-item ">
                            <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="/index.html">Home Page</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                            <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" role="button"
                                data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                                Example 1
                            </a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
                                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Example 2</a></li>
                                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Example 3</a></li>
                                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Example 4</a></li>
                                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Example 5</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>

                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Example 6</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Example 7/a>
                        </li>

                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Example8</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Example9</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link yesil" href="/search-page.html">SearchPage</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
        <div class="arkaplan yukseklik">

            I want to show search results in here

        </div>
        <div class="footer">
            <span>Copyright © 2022</span>

        </div>
    </div>

    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.10.2/dist/umd/popper.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-7+zCNj/IqJ95wo16oMtfsKbZ9ccEh31eOz1HGyDuCQ6wgnyJNSYdrPa03rtR1zdB"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-QJHtvGhmr9XOIpI6YVutG+2QOK9T+ZnN4kzFN1RtK3zEFEIsxhlmWl5/YESvpZ13"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found a solution for my question from a source. **Firstly i want to share my updated `index.html`:** Important code is under the `</nav>` tag and above the `</body>` tag. I put the searchbar under the navbar.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ka7Sk0Gln4gmtz2MlQnikT1wXgYsOg+OMhuP+IlRH9sENBO0LRn5q+8nbTov4+1p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<title>Example Website</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
            <div class="container-fluid">
              <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
              <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
              </button>
              <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
                <ul class="navbar-nav">
                  <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Home Page</a>
                  </li>
                  <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Google</a>
                  </li>
                  <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Custom</a>
                  </li>
                  <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link disabled">Search</a>
                  </li>
                </ul>
              </div>
            </div>
          </nav>
          <script src="/search.js" async defer></script>
          <gcse:searchbox-only resultsUrl="/search-page.html"></gcse:searchbox-only>
    </body>
    </html>
```

**Secondly i want to share `search-page.html` . You should redirect your results another page.** Important code is again under the `</nav>` tag and above the `</body>` tag in `form` element

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">
   <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ka7Sk0Gln4gmtz2MlQnikT1wXgYsOg+OMhuP+IlRH9sENBO0LRn5q+8nbTov4+1p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <title>Example Website</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
            <div class="container-fluid">
              <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
              <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
              </button>
              <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
                <ul class="navbar-nav">
                  <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Home Page</a>
                  </li>
                  <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Google</a>
                  </li>
                  <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Custom</a>
                  </li>
                  <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link disabled">Search</a>
                  </li>
                </ul>
              </div>
            </div>
          </nav>
          <form>
            <script async src="https://cse.google.com/cse.js?cx=1234567890"></script>
            <div class="gcse-search"></div>
        </form>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Finally you need a javascript code . I used it externally if you want you can use internally. For internal js code you can use `script type="module"` for deferring. You should enter your google custom search code in front of `var cx =` . Js code should be in the index.html between `</nav>` and `</body>` tags. I wrote it as search.js

```
(function () {
    var cx = '1234567890';
    var gcse = document.createElement('script');
    gcse.type = 'text/javascript';
    gcse.async = true;
    gcse.src = 'https://cse.google.com/cse.js?cx=' + cx;
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    s.parentNode.insertBefore(gcse, s);
})();
```

You can see original page in this link: [Source](https://kb.iu.edu/d/bckj)